# Netilat Yadayim - Ritual hand washing in the morning

Tags: halacha, sources-mekorot, blessing, netilat-yadayim-washing, ruach-rah

A question about *netilat yadayim* (ritual hand washing) upon waking up in the morning. Where does the custom with the bowl and cup by one's bed come from?

In modern homes with clear running water, is there a problem reciting the *bracha* whilst washing one’s hands in the sink?

Comment: Is your question about the bowl, the cup, or both? The answer you accepted only explains the bowl, but not why we use a cup. If that was your question, consider an [edit] to clarify.

Comment: You’re adding a new level of detail. My original question was like “why use the bedside kit when the sink is five steps away”. Usually chabad.org provides good insights but in this subject their article was mainly about the “how” and not so much the “why”.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Machatzitz Hashekel Orach Chaim 4,1:3 quotes the Bach from Tolaas Yaakov in the name of the Zohar that one shouldn't walk 4 cubits after waking up in the morning without washing ones hands Netilas Yodayim. So a bowl with a cup next to one's bed is the solution. But the Mordechai (Rishon) seems to be lenient that one can walk till the sink to wash ones hands with a cup. As long as one is under one roof this is considered like walking no more than 4 cubits (only outdoors 4 cubits is relevant) as this Halacha is not mentioned explicitly in the Gemora.

> כ' הב"ח בשם ת"י **ההולך ד' אמות בשחרית קודם שנטל ידיו חייב מיתה** ותמה הב"ח על הרב בית יוסף שהשמיטו ואולי משום מוטב יהיו שוגגים כו'. ובס' אליה רבה סי' א' הביא בשם גיסו ה"ה מהרר"י בעל מנחת יעקב שאמר ליישב מנהג העולם שסומכים ע"ד המרדכי שהביא ש"ך יורה דעה סימן שד"מ בהא דאמרינן אין אומרים בפני המת אלא דבריו של מת. וכ' רב האי גאון דוקא תוך ד' אמות של מת וכ' המרדכי דכל תחתיו נחשב כד"א וא"כ ה"ה כאן מותר לילך בכל החדר קודם נטילה. ובעל א"ר דחה דהא קי"ל בכל דוכתי גם לענין צואה בבית דאין כל החדר נחשב לד' אמות א"כ קשיין דברי המרדכי אעכצ"ל דהמרדכי לא אמרה אלא לגבי מת **דלא הוזכר בפי' בגמ' שיעור ד' אמות לכן להאי טעמא מסתבר למרדכי דכל החדר נחשב לענין זה כד' אמות**

If the sink is is in the restroom then one should refrain saying the Brocha till walking out of the restroom. as it is a dirty place, but a sink outside the restroom is not a dirty place and one can make a Brocho. Mishna Brura 3,1,3:

> אך יראה בעת הברכה להרחיק מהעביט של המי רגליים 
>   ארבע אמות אם הוא עומד בחדרו

Comment: I see a checkmark but don't understand how this answers the question. I thought the question was about pouring water over the hands versus washing them as usual, without a cup.

Comment: I get the answer. The walk to the sink exceeds the prescribed distance of 4 cubits (like 2 meters).

Comment: I do feel this is a rather legalistic point of view. “don’t go four cubits before...” might also translate to “don’t start your day before...”. But then, these kind of philosophical differences are omnipresent in Judaism.